# Alternatives to rrdtool?

Tags: java, database, real-time, rrdtool

I'm looking for an alternative to the [rrdtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/index.en.html)

It need to be fast, reliable, able to handle large amounts of data and have a Java interface. One possibilty I'm investigating is [KDB+](http://kx.com/Products/kdb+.php) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are two Java ports of RRD: [rrd4j](https://github.com/rrd4j/rrd4j) and [JRobin](http://www.jrobin.org)

If you just want a replacement for RRDTool, K is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

JRobin is outdated and no longer developed. RRD4J is the way forward.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it is commentary on another answer and also duplicates information given in a previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [RRD4J](https://github.com/rrd4j/rrd4j)?

EDIT: RRD4J, which Nat pointed out, is a port of [JRobin](http://www.jrobin.org/index.php/Main_Page).  At this point, it looks  like JRobin is more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to JRobin. I use it for [my project](http://code.google.com/p/rrdws/issues/list) .